# Get workflow id in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, workflow

Can we get workflow id if we have workflow name in Powershell script?

**Scenario** 1:
I have workflow name "Test workflow"
based on its name can I get its id in Powershell script?

**Scenario** 2:

Can we get workflow state id as well if I have workflow state name in Powershell script?

Comment: So you mean that you don't have path and ID of the item, only name and using that you want to identify the workflow ID and it's details right?

Comment: Yes @SumitBhatia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you would like to get workflow `ID` based on workflow name only.

For your first scenario try this approach :

```
(Get-Item  -Path  "master:/sitecore/system/Workflows/<your workflow name>").ID
```

For your second scenario try the same approach and add your workflow state name like below :

```
(Get-Item  -Path  "master:/sitecore/system/Workflows/<your workflow name>/<your workflow state name>").ID
```

Comment: Able to get id here. Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1:**

As we discussed in comments, If you don't have the `Path` and `ID` of the `workflow item` then you need to use a `Query` to get the item like below.

```
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/system/Workflows//*[@@templatename='Workflow']" | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "<Your Workflow Name>"}
```

So in the above query, we have to provide the location where `Sitecore` maintains all the workflows. i.e. `/sitecore/system/Workflows`

Using the above query, it will get all the items by filtering with the template name and item name.

**Scenario 2:**

Using the same approach we will get the children of the `Workflow` that we get from the query and then loop through its child items to identify the `state` like this.

```
$workflow = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "/sitecore/system/Workflows//*[@@templatename='Workflow']" | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "<Your state name>"} 

Get-ChildItem -ID $workflow.Id | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Deployed"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was showing full details of the item along with the id. I need only id of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the workflow id by using the below -

**Scenario 1:**

1st way - `(Get-Item master: -ID $_."__Workflow state").Name`

2nd way -

```
Get-ItemWorkflowEvent -Path master:\content\home
```

Output will be like this -

```
Date     : 2014-07-27 14:23:33
NewState : {190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}
OldState : {46DA5376-10DC-4B66-B464-AFDAA29DE84F}
Text     : Automated
User     : sitecore\admin

Date     : 2014-08-01 15:43:29
NewState : {190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}
OldState : {190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}
Text     : Just leaving a note
User     : sitecore\admin
```

Follow this - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemworkflowevent

**Scenario 2:** Try this, I haven't tested this.

```
(Get-Item master: -Name $_."__Workflow state").ID
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:**
You can get an Id based on the path of workflow, like below:

```
Get-Item  -Path  "master:/sitecore/system/Workflows/Analytics Testing Workflow"
```

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

If you have different states in workflow like below:

[image]

You need to do the similar thing which you did in Scenario 1, need to pass `state` path and it will return the ID